# What are these entries in the database? Looks similar to JSON

Tags: plugins, database

So I have been wondering for a while now what these entries are and what they do, also what the format of them are. They look similar to JSON but are definitely not JSON.

```
a:1:{s:12:"jetlocations";a:2:{s:5:"label";s:12:"JetLocations";s:4:"type";s:6:"editor";}}
```

I have searched to try and find out what these might be but come up with nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a [Serialized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) Array which turns an array into a simple string so that it can be inserted into a database ( since you cannot just insert arrays into a database as they are ).

For more information you can read into the PHP docs for [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

There is also some WordPress functions which do the same: [`maybe_serialize()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) and [`maybe_unserialize()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize).

This usually happens ( automatically ) whenever you pass an array to the [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function. In order to get the array back, you can use [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) and pass in a true value to `$single`.

> **$single**
>
> (boolean) (optional) If set to true then the function will return a single result, as a string. If false, or not set, then the function returns an array of the custom fields. This may not be intuitive in the context of serialized arrays. **If you fetch a serialized array with this method you want $single to be true to actually get an unserialized array back.** If you pass in false, or leave it out, you will have an array of one, and the value at index 0 will be the serialized string.
>
> *Default: false*

[`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) will also return an unserialized array ready for use by default.

---

If we break down the string it looks like this:

```
a:1:{s:12:"jetlocations";a:2:{s:5:"label";s:12:"JetLocations";s:4:"type";s:6:"editor";}}
```

`a:1:{}` = Specifies that there is an array with a count of 1

`s:12:` = The only index in the array is a string of 12 characters long - "jetlocations"

`a:2:` = jetlocations then holds an array with the count of 2

`s:5:` = The first index is a string of 5 characters long - "label"

`s:12:` = The value of "label" is also a string of 12 characers long - "JetLocations"

`s:4:` = Our second index is a string of 4 characters logn - "type"

`s:6:` = The value of "type" is a string of 6 characters long - "editor"

So if we put this all together we get an array that looks like this:

```
array(
    'jetlocations' => array(
        'label' => 'JetLocations',
        'type'  => 'editor'
    )
);
```