# how to read database fields

Tags: database

Can someone please explain how to read the letters, numbers, and colons in the wordpress database?

For example:

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
```

in the wp-capabilities table.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are these entries in the database? Looks similar to JSON](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169035/what-are-these-entries-in-the-database-looks-similar-to-json)

Comment: I use jsfiddle.net 's javascript block to paste the serialized value and hit "TidyUp" button to make them a bit readable. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are php serialized constructs.  The one you have there is an array.  If you are looking to read them as a human, it breaks down like this:

```
Array: a:size:{key definition;value definition;(repeated per element)}
String: s:size:value
```

There are other possibilities that you can read more about [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147).

Generally, you should never modify these directly since unless you do it perfectly you will break the record.  To manipulate them with php you'd `unserialize()`, manipulate, and then re`serialize()`. e.g.

```
//get $my_serialized_variable from database
$value = unserialize($my_serialized_variable);
$value[] = $element_i_want_to_add;
$serial = serialize($value);
//write serial to database
```

If you absolutely have to modify it in the database, use a tool like [this](https://www.functions-online.com/serialize.html) to make sure you have a valid serial.