# WP_OPTIONS table, active_plugins entry

Tags: php, options

I asked it [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_options-table-active_plugins-entry) and found no response so far.

Here is a sample entry from the **active_plugins** line of WP_OPTIONS table:

> a:5:{i:0;s:35:"add-from-server/add-from-server.php";i:1;s:25:"age-verify/age-verify.php";i:2;s:19:"jetpack/jetpack.php";i:4;s:69:"simple-full-screen-background-image/simple-full-screen-background.php";i:6;s:27:"wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php";}

My question is what are these **s:** entries? **(s:35, s:19, s:27)**

Comment: It's serialized data. The **s:** indicates the length of the string that follows.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169036/7355), Gabriel is right it is serialized data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That entry is a [PHP serialized array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). The `serialize` method takes an array and stores it's value as a string so it can be stored elsewhere - like a database.

In the above example, the "s:" entries stand for "string:". With a serialized array, each element's data type is represented by a letter (a, s, o, etc) followed by a colon, then an optional length, and then a value. So...

> a:5:{i:0;s:35:"add-from-server/add-from-server.php"

```
 a:5:{... - array, 5 elements 
 i:0 - integer, value of 0
 s:35:"add-from-server/add-from-server.php" - a string that is 35 characters long, and then the string itself
```

Edit: by the way, you should always interact with these by using the PHP methods to `serialize` and `unserialize` - if you removed the ".php" from that string above, you would break serialization unless you also changed the length in "s:35" to "s:31" (since four characters were removed). It's easy to break a WordPress installation by hand-editing serialized arrays.

Comment: Many many t h a n k s! @phatskat