# How to parse wordpress options json

Tags: parse

I have the data saved using a plugin in this format:

```
a:7:{s:6:'Sunday ';a:3:{s:6:'active ';s:3:'yes ';s:5:'start ';s:5:'08: 00 ';s:3:'end ';s:5:'13: 00 ';}
    s:6:'Monday ';a:3:{s:6:'active ';s:3:'yes ';s:5:'start ';s:5:'08: 00 ';s:3:' end ';s:5:'17: 00 ';}
    s:7:'Tuesday ';a:3:{s:6:' active ';s:3:'yes ';s:5:'start ';s:5:'08: 00 ';s:3:'end ';s:5:'17: 00 ';}
    s:9:'Wednesday ';a:3:{s:6:'active ';s:3:'yes ';s:5:'start ';s:5:'08: 00 ';s:3:'end ';s:5:'17: 00 ';}
    s:8:'Thursday ';a:3:{s:6:'active ';s:3:'yes ';s:5:'start ';s:5:'08: 00 ';s:3:'end ';s:5:'17: 00 ';}
    s:6:'Friday ';a:3:{s:6:'active ';s:3:'yes ';s:5:'start ';s:5:'08: 00 ';s:3:'end ';s:5:'17: 00 ';}
    s:8:'Saturday ';a:3:{s:6:'active ';s:3:'yes ';s:5:'start ';s:5:'08: 00 ';s:3:'end ';s:5:'13: 00 ';}}
```

How can I extract this data using php or any WordPress functions?
I have already tried `unserialize()`, `maybe_unserialize()` `json_decode` . But all I get is null in the end.

Comment: Who knows!!! Have you tried `json_decode()`?

Comment: The problem with this question is: no one knows what you are trying to do. Give us more information.

Comment: Yes I have tried `json_encode()` but it gives me null in response.
The plugin saves the data in this format in database. SO what I need to to extract this data in array to display on template.

Comment: This is not a valid json, as I validated this. But there should be a way to get the values inside?

Comment: I tried to parse your JSON into [this](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and got an error that _SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data_. Please correct it first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are these entries in the database? Looks similar to JSON](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169035/what-are-these-entries-in-the-database-looks-similar-to-json)

Comment: Dude, are you sure this isn't just a serialized array from the database? What is the purpose you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using the plugin [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/appointments/)Appointment And the appointments are saved in such format. What I need is to fetch the time to match a particular time I have.

Comment: Please describe how you extracted this data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comments and answers are correct, it is no JSON but indeed a [serialized array](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169036/7355). The reason you're having trouble *unserializing* it is because of the quotes inside the serialized data. [David Walsh wrote a neat article about this](https://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues). The problem is that you can't simply go into the database and remove these single quotes because the serialized value keeps track of the number of characters in the string (`s:6`) so you would also need to update that.

Here's what David Walsh suggests to get around this issue in the future:

```
//to safely serialize
$safe_string_to_store = base64_encode( serialize( $multidimensional_array ) );

//to unserialize...
$array_restored_from_db = unserialize( base64_decode( $encoded_serialized_string ) );
```

Comment: This answer is not good. We have https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_serialized for that.

Comment: @NathanPowell The data is clearly serialized but corrupt which is why it can't be unserialized. [`is_serialized()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_serialized/) only checks  if it's a string not if it's valid data. The point of base64 encoding is if you _need_ to store things with singe/double quotes.

Comment: Granted, but that is not the clear answer here. We have no idea how this "format" was achieved. I like to think WordPress doesn't need to be hacked when answering here.

Comment: Also, how do you see the data corrupt?

Comment: @NathanPowell You can try to unserialize it. I used an [online tool](https://www.functions-online.com/unserialize.html) which I've used in the past.

Comment: Not WordPress. This is what I am talking about. Answers without proof. This is WordPress. This kid got data without using the convention. Don't give answers without knowing stuff. This is simple.

Comment: @NathanPowell No need to be rude - I posted this as an answer as I've run into this issue in the past using conventional `post_meta` allowing WordPress to serialize my data. I'm just trying to help people solve issues using my past experiences.

Comment: Why use WordPress then? Best practice and all. We don't need to hack this software to use it agile. I'm not rude.

Comment: @NathanPowell I did not extract this data - I keep getting corrupt errors form what i assume is quotes in the serialized data. The method I posted was for future reference if OP ran into this issue / could replicate the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry @Howdy_McGee, I respect your answer.

Comment: The user is not extracting the data properly.

Comment: Looking again at this tonight. Thanks for the great article @Howdy_McGee. I most certainly see the issue. The serialized array is not escaped properly when saved, therefore it comes back with corruption. I think it is important to note that this is a "hack" to extract what _could_ be potentially malicious code that is saved. If best practices are used to *save* the data in the above array, this "hack" would not need to be used.